# bindService not working inside a button click but works in onCreate - android

Tags: android, binding, service, oncreate

I have a pretty simple local service that I'm trying to bind to my activity.  I worked through this yesterday with CommonsWare and he got me straightened out as I was having a difficult time getting the service to bind.  It turns out that the reason I was having so much trouble was that I was trying to bind the service with:

```
bindService(new Intent(this, myService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

inside a void method that was being called after a button click.

```
private void doBindService() {
            bindService(new Intent(this, SimpleService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            mIsBound = true;
        }

       private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            doBindService();
        }               
       };
```

when I moved my bindService() call to the onCreate method of the activity, it works fine. CommonsWare mentioned something about that call being asynchronous and I don't know enough about android activity creation to know if that's what my issue was or not.  I do know that my onServiceConnection() was being called inside my ServiceConnection() when the button was being clicked, by my mBoundService would not work when I tried accessing members inside the service.

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work inside the button click, but does work inside the onCreate()?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` reference inside of `doBindService` is not the same in both instances. If called in `onCreate` it will be a reference to the `Activity` if called from the button click it will be a reference to the `OnClickListener`. Obviously you do not want your service bound to the buttons click listener.

Try changing `this` to `YOURACTIVITYNAME.this` and see if that helps.

Comment: @chris324 - thanks for the reply, but if you look more carefully, the bindService() gets called from a void method that's part of the activity class which is called from the click.  So for all intents and purposes, 'this' would refer to the activity would it not?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter where the function is defined. It's called from a different class and thus the `this` will point to that